# Apply for credit card again after being rejected

Tags: united-states, credit-card, credit-score

I already have one discover credit card and I recently applied for Wells Fargo credit card. But it got rejected saying that I am not a US resident. 
Something about me:- I am a student doing masters in the US and have done some paid internships in past.

Now, I wanted to apply again for another credit. Since my last rejection was only 2 weeks back, so my question is:- Is it advisable/okay to apply for another card after 2 weeks of rejection?

Comment: After being told "no", **and why**, what makes you think that a measly two week wait is going to change your immigration status?

Comment: No that's not my point man. I am not again applying to the same credit card. And obviously immigration status won't change but that does not mean I cannot apply for credit card ever. There are many banks which offer the credit card to students also.

Comment: FOR credit cards and loans in india CIBIL score is very important after checking centralized CIBIL score of individual card will be issued

Comment: You're not a US resident, your income is low, and you could leave the country at any time, thus stiffing the bank for $1000 or more.  Please don't wonder why no bank in their right mind would offer you a second card.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, plenty of institutions will lend small amounts to you.

You just need to get better at filling out the forms. Why does one bank consider you not a US resident? Get a US address.

Comment: Surely the "why does one bank consider you not a US citizen" comes down to some form of the question: "are you a US citizen", rather than just an address check?

Comment: @Philbo a) this is about residency and not citizenship b) you have assumed great amounts about what banks care about and what the laws actually say

Comment: It probably comes down to the SSN field.